# Что не так с закодированием пароля?

Tags: php, rsa, steam-web-api

Что то не так с закодированием пароля?
Постоянно выдает что пароль не правильный, хотя он правильный на 100%.

```
    $username = $this->request->getContent['login'];
    $password = $this->request->getContent['password'];


    $url = 'https://store.steampowered.com/login/getrsakey/';
    $data = ['username' => $username, 'password' => $password];

    $result = $this->post($url, $data);
    $result = json_decode($result);

    $rsa = new RSA();
    $key = [
        'modulus'        => new BigInteger($result->publickey_mod, 16),
        'publicExponent' => new BigInteger($result->publickey_exp, 16)
    ];

    $rsa->loadKey($key, RSA::PUBLIC_FORMAT_RAW);
    $password = base64_encode($rsa->encrypt($password, false));
    $captchaGid = -1;
    $captchaText = '';
    $emailAuth = '';
    $emailSteamId = '';

    $data = [
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password,
        'rsatimestamp' => $result->timestamp,
        'captcha_gid' => $captchaGid,
        'captcha_text' => $captchaText,
        'emailauth' => $emailAuth,
        'emailsteamid' => $emailSteamId
    ];

    $url = 'https://store.steampowered.com/login/dologin/';

    $result = $this->post($url, $data);
    $result= json_decode($result);

    $this->response->setJsonContent($result)->send();
}

private function post($url, $data) {
    $curl_handle=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    $query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    curl_close($curl_handle);

    return $query;
```

Comment: за что отвечает второй параметр здесь `$rsa->encrypt($password, false)`?

Comment: это ограничение строки

Comment: Проблему решил, нужно было добавить $rsa->setEncryptionMode(RSA::ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);